# Error 2467 filtering a subform in a form in a navigation

Tags: ms-access, vba, subform

I have a form with 1 dropdown and 4 subreports, called rptBuildingResume. When I choose a value in the dropdown I filter all the subforms using that value. This works fine but...

I have a navigation form, called Main, when I add the previous form into my navigation form, of course I change my code, and this

> 2467 error

start to appear, but the fun thing is that it works fine for the first subreport, but fails for the next one. If I change the order of the callings it works allways fine for the first one, but fail in the next.

This is the code I´m using to do this:

```
[Forms]![Main]!SubformNav.[Form].rptNotFinishedBld.Report.Filter = "BuildingID_FK = " & Me.Building
[Forms]![Main]!SubformNav.[Form].rptNotFinishedBld.Report.FilterOn = True
[Forms]![Main]!SubformNav.[Form].rptNosPaidInFullBld.Report.Filter = "BuildingID_FK = " & Me.Building
[Forms]![Main]!SubformNav.[Form].rptNosPaidInFullBld.Report.FilterOn = True
[Forms]![Main]!SubformNav.[Form].rptDoneBld.Report.Filter = "BuildingID_FK >= " & Me.Building
[Forms]![Main]!SubformNav.[Form].rptDoneBld.Report.FilterOn = True
[Forms]![Main]!SubformNav.[Form].rptAgreeDepositNoStartBld.Report.Filter = "BuildingID_FK = " & Me.Building
[Forms]![Main]!SubformNav.[Form].rptAgreeDepositNoStartBld.Report.FilterOn >= True
```

- **Main** is my navigation form.
- **SubformNav** is the subform in it.
- **rpt*** are the subreports in the subform.

Comment: thanks, braX, for your help editing my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is an inbuilt navigation form then it is caused by the way the inbuilt Navigation form work - I would have a read here https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=286675 for some explanations of Cause and effect.

If not then you need to look at the syntax examples here http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm for the correct way to reference sub forms from other forms / subforms.

Edit: The alternative would be to use the Child/Master properties of the subreports to negate having to filter them, probably more efficient as well.

Comment: I check the links you sent me but it is the same, I made some minor changes based on that, adding [] in some places it wasn't, but the result is the same :(

Comment: The inbuilt Navigation form only has one (the selected tab) of the Navigation Tabs forms actually loaded at any given time. So if you are trying to set or inquire about any other forms on your navigation form they won't actually be there. 
It's why most experienced developers "roll their own" navigation forms or switchboards.

Comment: yes, I understand that, I'm trying to filter 4 subreports insigth the selected tab form, I mean, I have a form with one dropdown and 4 sub reports, and this form is the selected tab

Comment: Okay - it may be to do with the fact that these are reports in forms.
Try this syntax 
[Forms]![Main]!SubformNav.[Form]![YourSubReportContainerName].Report.Filter

Comment: yes, that is what I'm doing, and it works fine for the first report but fail in the next :(

Comment: Make careful note of the ! as opposed to the dot. Apart from that It seems odd that one works and not the others. Have you considered using the child/master settings to "filter" the sub forms?

Comment: ¡Thanks a lot!, I change it to use child/master and it works

Comment: Glad you have it sorted. I'll Edit my answer if you would like to accept it.

Comment: sorry, Minty, I'm not sure how I can accept an answer, can you tell me?

Comment: oh, I think I just did :)